# React-Native: "RNCSafeAreaProvider" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: android

I am facing this issue when I want to use material-bottom-tabs.
How can I solve?

[Code Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whjNb.png)

```json
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
"@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.9",
"@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.16",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
"axios": "^1.4.0",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-native": "^0.72.3",
"react-native-config": "^1.5.1",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.0",
"react-native-paper": "^5.9.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.17.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.1",
"react-native-screens": "^3.22.1",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0"
}
```

I tried different versions. I deleted and reinstalled node_modules. Furthermore, I added `react-native-screens` to `settings.gradle` And finally to MainApplication.java `packages.add(new com.swmansion.rnscreens.RNScreensPackage());` I added the code. But the problem is still the same.